# Allocate memory (x64 assembly)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, memory, assembly, 64-bit, allocation

How can I allocate memory in the Heap in x64 assembly. I want to store the value of the sidt function, but I can't seem to find a way on how to do so?

I use Visual studio 2012.

Comment: `sidt` has a tiny and fixed-sized result, do you even need heap memory for it? Should be easy to put in statically allocated data memory

Comment: Even if I define a tbyte pointer in the data section and I use that pointer, sidt will return gibberish.

Comment: Any reason to code an entire function in assembly in 2015? You'll probably would do worse than most compilers!

Comment: Gibberish like what? It should be a 16bit size followed by a 64bit pointer

Comment: It doesn't return the right pointer. It returns the right pointer occasionally :(

Comment: "...returns the right pointer occasionally..."  This makes me think that you actually have some other problem here.  It would be good if you could post the code where the pointer is only occasionally correct.

Answer (score 1):

You will have two options (assuming you're running in user space on top of an operating system).

1. use whatever your operating system provides to map you some writable memory (in UNIX `brk`/`sbrk`/`mmap`)
2. call the `malloc` library function in the C standard library (which will do (1) under the hood for you)

I'd go for number 2 as it's much simpler and kind of portable.

Something similar to the following should do the trick:

```
movq $0x10, %rdi
callq malloc
; %rax will now contain the pointer to the memory
```

Assuming ADM64 ([System V AMD64 ABI](http://people.freebsd.org/~obrien/amd64-elf-abi.pdf)) calling conventions, that'll call `malloc(16)` which should return you a pointer to a memory block with 16 bytes. The address should reside in the `%rax` register after the call returns (or `0` if not enough memory).

EDIT: Wikipedia says about the [x86-64 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention) that Microsoft apparently uses a different calling convention (first register in `RCX` not `RDI`). So you'd need to modify `movl $0x10, %rdi` to `movl $0x10, %rcx`.

Comment: My computer has an Intel processor. I tried calling malloc, but when I try to compile it, it says that it is an unknown symbol.

Comment: @FredericaBernkastel can you try `callq _malloc`. Depends a bit on your linker what exactly you'll have to do to call a `libc` function. You might also need to tell it to link `libc`. Maybe just make a C program where you call malloc, disassemble it and then you'll see what it takes.

Comment: possibly also `.extern _malloc` or `.extern malloc` or whatever your assembler uses to mark an external symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your environment, I'm guessing that you're writing assembly code in Windows.  You'll need to use the Windows equivelent to an `sbrk` system call.  You may find [this MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366533(VS.85).aspx) useful!

Answer (score 0):

Write the code to call malloc in C, then have the compiler produce an assembly listing, which will show you the name used for malloc (probably _malloc in the case of Microsoft compilers), and how to call it.

Another option would be to allocate space from the stack with a subtract from esp, equal to the size of a structure that will hold the sidt information.